# Sequelize returning different values than the raw query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

When I run this function

```
function getOpenTxCalls(date) {
 return sequelize.query(
 'SELECT \
  CT.center_name, \
  COUNT(CASE WHEN CL.disposition_type IN(3, 4, 22, 23,25, 42) AND CL."createdAt"::date = :date THEN CL.disposition_type END) AS "CallsMadeToday", \
  COUNT(CASE WHEN CL.disposition_type = 3 AND CL."createdAt"::date = :date THEN CL.disposition_type END) AS "AppointmentsMadeToday" \
FROM "Centers" AS CT \
 LEFT JOIN "Users" AS US ON US."centerId" = CT.id \
 LEFT JOIN "CallLogs" AS CL ON CL."createdBy" = US."id"  \
WHERE US."centerId" NOT IN(11, 13)\
GROUP BY CT.center_name \
ORDER BY CT.center_name',
{ replacements:
  {
    date: date
  },
  type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
.then(function(openTXCalls) {
  console.log(openTXCalls);
  return openTXCalls;
})
.catch(console.log.bind(console));
}
```

It's returning incorrect data.

I watched the CLI as I ran the function and copy and pasted the SQL query in CLI into PG3 Admin and received different (correct) values.  Here is what was in the CLI.

```
Executing (default): SELECT     
CT.center_name,     
COUNT(CASE WHEN    CL.disposition_type IN(3, 4, 22, 23,25, 42) AND CL."createdAt"::date = '2016-02-17' THEN CL.disposition_type END) AS "CallsMadeToday",     
COUNT(CASE WHEN CL.disposition_type = 3 AND CL."createdAt"::date = '2016-02-17' THEN CL.disposition_type END) AS "AppointmentsMadeToday"   
FROM "Centers" AS CT     
LEFT JOIN "Users" AS US ON US."centerId" = CT.id     
LEFT JOIN "CallLogs" AS CL ON CL."createdBy" = US."id"    
WHERE US."centerId" NOT IN(11, 13)  
GROUP BY CT.center_name   
ORDER BY CT.center_name
```

I am querying the same local Postgres database on my machine.  Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Comment: How is the data incorrect?

Comment: The counts are wrong.  I know looking at the table it should return X number of rows (which is what the PG3 Admin Query pulls) but Sequelize returns Y.